# Glue div to bottom of other div (not bottom of window)

Tags: html, css

So I want a div to always be on the bottom of another div it's in.
I've used bottom:0, position: absolute. This works as long as the window is the same size as the main div (which is the size of the windows too), but the main div has a min-height set, when the window gets smaller then this height the div start moving up with the bottom of the window.
vertical-align also doesn't work for this purpose as it glues it to the bottom of the other divs in the main div, but that results in it not being in the bottom of the main div, which is my goal.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `position:relative` on the parent `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox for that:

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to make sure that a div is always anchored to the bottom of a div, no matter what. In that case, all you need to do is make sure that the parent div has position:relative, while the child has position: absolute and is absolutely positioned to the bottom of the div.

Screen size shouldn't affect this, even if the parent div has a min-height.

But if I'm off, if you post your code, we may be able to better help.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.parent {
    position: relative;
    min-height:--px
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as just regular position: absolute; bottom: 0; sticks to the bottom of window (when the windows is smaller then the div in height) not div.